# Talend avoid duplicate external ID with Salesforce Output

Tags: salesforce, talend

We are importing data on Salesforce through Talend and we have multiple items with the same internal id.

Such import fails with error "Duplicate external id specified" because of how upsert works in Salesforce. At the moment, we worked that around by using the commit size of the tSalesforceOutput to 1, but that works only for small amount of data or it would exhaust Salesforce API Limits.

Is there a known approach to it in Talend? For example, to ensure items that have same external ID ends up in different "commits" of tSalesforceOutput?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the design for the solution I wish to propose:
[image]

- tSetGlobalVar is here to initialize the variable "finish" to false.
- tLoop starts a while loop with `(Boolean)globalMap.get("finish") == false` as an end condition.
- tFileCopy is used to copy the initial file (A for example) to a new one (B).
- tFileInputDelimited reads file B.
- tUniqRow eliminates duplicates. Uniques records go to tLogRow you have to replace by tSalesforceOutput. Duplicates records if any go to tFileOutputDelimited called A (same name as the original file) with the option "Throw an error if the file already exist" unchecked.
- OnComponent OK after tUniqRow activates the tJava which set the new value for the global finish with the following code:
  `if (((Integer)globalMap.get("tUniqRow_1_NB_DUPLICATES")) == 0) globalMap.put("finish", true);`

Explaination with the following sample data:
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 2
line 4
line 2
line 5
line 3

On the 1st iteration, 5 uniques records are pushed into tLogRow, 3 duplicates are pushed into file A and "finish" is not changed as there is duplicates.
On the 2nd iteration, operations are repeated for 2 uniques records and 1 duplicate.
On the 3rd iteration, operations are repeated for 1 unique and as there not anymore duplicate, "finish" is set to true and the loop automatically finishes.

Here is the final result:
[image]

You can also decide to use an other global variable to set the salesforce commit level (using the syntax `(Integer)globalMap.get("commitLevel")`). This variable will be set to 200 by default and to 1 in the tJava if any duplicates. At the same time, set "finish" to true (without testing the number of duplicates) and you'll have a commit level to 200 for the 1st iteration and to 1 for the 2nd (and no need more than 2 iterations).
You'll decide the better choice depending on the number of potential duplicates, but you can notice that you can do it whitout any change to the job design.

I think it should solve your problem. Let me know.

Regards,
TRF

Comment: After reviewing my 2nd option, it appears it will a little more complicated that what I wrote as tUniqRow need to be bypassed during the 2bd iteration. If you want to adopt this solution, replace tJava by a tJavaRow and add a 2nd tSalesforceOutput after it with commit level set to 1. Finally it is a different process. You just have to choose which one is better for your use case.

Comment: I am not sure of why the content of the file would change at each iteration and therefore the duplicates number will change

Comment: Because at each iteration WE get the 1st record for a given ID and push the duplicates to the file which will count less records at each time.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you have the same record (the same account for example) twice or more in the input?
If so, can't you try to eliminate the duplicates and keep only the record you need to push to Salesforce?
Else, if each record has specific informations (so you need all the input records to have a complete one in Salesforce), consider to merge the records before to push the result into Salesforce.
And finally, if you can't do that, push the doublons in a temporary space, push the records but the doublons into Salesforce and iterate other this process until there is no more doublons.
Personally, if you can't just eliminate the doublons, I prefer the 2nd approach as it's the solution to have less Salesforce API calls.

Hope this helps.
TRF

Comment: Can you provide more details about "push the doublons in the temporary space and iterate the process"? How is this done in Talend?

Comment: I mean push the result to a tHashOutput or a delimited file, as you prefer

Comment: That's ok, but what about the process iteration? That's the part I didn't understand

Comment: Use tLoop to design a tasks set for which you want to iterate. Configure the tLoop as a "while loop" with no Declaration and no Iteration values and use a global (or context) variable to define the Condition (to stop the loop). For example, the condition can be "(Boolean)globalMap.get("finish")". The variable finish is set to False at the begenning and to True as soon as there is no more duplicate record. Do you need more details?

Comment: yes please this is super valuable! if you could provide more details on how to set the finish variable it would be really great.

Comment: Add a tJava after the tUniqRow to set the variable: 
`if (((Integer)globalMap.get("tUniqRow_1_NB_DUPLICATES")) == 0)
 globalMap.put("finish", true);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153693/discussion-between-edmondo1984-and-trf).